# load a js file with a component after certain other scripts in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to load my own js file in which I have written some custom js that requires jQuery. I want to load my js file after the jQuery, how I can do it. I dont want to put this script file in index.html because then it will load with every component.

This is my js file

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Pro</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <!-- Material Design for Bootstrap fonts and icons -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <!-- Material Design for Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-material-design@4.0.0-beta.3/dist/css/bootstrap-material-design.min.css" integrity="sha384-k5bjxeyx3S5yJJNRD1eKUMdgxuvfisWKku5dwHQq9Q/Lz6H8CyL89KF52ICpX4cL" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <app-root></app-root>
  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The main question is how to load a script file after certain other scripts and laod only with a related component. login.js should load only with login page.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to include it in the "scripts" section of your .angular-cli.json file, if it is a node module:

```
 "scripts": [
              "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "../node_modules/bootstrap-switch/dist/js/bootstrap-switch.min.js",
]
```

then, create an Injection token, and Inject it as a dependency to your main.ts module and component

```
// call this file 'mylib.lib.ts'
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
import * as myLib from '../../node_modules/myModule`;

export const libToken = new InjectionToken('libName');
export const libName = myLib
export * from 'libName';
```

Inject the dependency into your module:

```
...
import * as mylib from './mylib.lib';
..
providers: [
    { provide: myLib.libToken, useValue: myLib.libName}
]
```

then you can add it to your component:

```
import { libName, libToken} from './mylib.lib';
...
constructor(@Inject(cesiumToken) private myLib: any) {}
```

and that should get you going.

Another rather messy way to do it is append the script to the main html file in your ts file inside the AfterViewInit hook:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {   
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = '../../assets/js/myFile.js';
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

for method one, just make sure it is the script after jquery, for method two, if will be last since it appends the tag after the DOM is rendered

Comment: how does it make sure that my js file is loaded after the jquery has loaded?

Comment: for method one, just make sure it is the script after jquery, for method two, if will be last since it appends the tag after the DOM is rendered

Comment: and in the first method it will also make sure that it will only load with the desired component.